# Is it performant to get a bunch of documents by their document ID in a loop?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Getting a bunch of documents from a Firestore collection is best done through a query, I fully understand that. However, in certain situations where we want to get a bunch of specific documents based on their document ID from a single collection (or even spanning multiple collections), is it performant in Firestore to loop through those document IDs (whether it's 10 or 1,000) on the client and perform a `getDocument()` call on each one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the best way to get the job done.  It's also the only way, unless you want to use an "in" query to fetch in batches (which I'm told is actually slower than fetching each one individually).

Comment: So Firestore doesn't start frowning when we call 100 `getDocument()` calls within 1 second in a loop? This is as "normal" (as far as the API is concerned) as performing a query, in some sense?

Comment: No, Firestore is massively scalable and very effective at heavy read loads.

Comment: @DougStevenson Is `query`, however, fundamentally preferred over iterating `getDocument` inside a loop? Or is there literally no difference in terms of the nuts and bolts of how Firestore operates?

Comment: I'm told by Firebase staff that iterating document gets is supposed to be faster than batching IN queries.  You can benchmark for yourself, but I personally wouldn't spend time trying to optimize a database product that massively scales document reads.

Comment: @DougStevenson I'm actually not interested in speed (I do both and the differences are less than negligible). My question is more of a conceptual/best-practices one. Suppose an app didn't even use queries (for whatever reason), they were all replaced with `getDocument` calls inside loops. In theory, no problem still?

Comment: Do whatever you need to do to get your documents. Make your code readable (my opinion).  It doesn't much matter to Firestore as long as you're willing to pay for your document reads.